# Cordova Connecting to device Android 2.1

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I try to run a Cordova application on an android 2.1, but I get only the message (Connecting to device) and the application never move to the (device ready) state
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could this version of Android be too old, I see in the [Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) that it supports 2.3.x and 4.x

Comment: So that means we can never use cordova on those devices?

Comment: Probably a state due to cache. Restart the app, or clear cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue... simply the cordova framwork do not support the android 2.1 and any other sdk version since it has less then 5% of market